# Tkinter GUI showing black screen after PyInstaller .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe, executable

I am creating a executable GUI using PyInstaller. Every time I create the .exe and open it, the Tkinter window is just a black screen. Here is what I typed into the terminal to create the app.

```
pyinstaller main.py --onefile --noconsole --add-data "./songs/*.mp3:." --add-binary "./driver/chromedriver:./driver"
```

More info that may be helpful: I am on a Mac running Big Sur 11.1. When using PyInstaller, I had to manually add my mp3 files as data. The program also uses Selenium to browse the web, so I manually added the Chrome web driver as a binary when using PyInstaller. I have a python file that includes a function that allows PyInstaller to properly find the paths of my .mp3 files and my web driver:

```
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

I have been searching for hours to no avail. I need my GUI to actually show up instead of just showing a black screen. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you try to create a [mre] and post it in your answer — doing so may also allow you to figure-out what the problem is yourself.